# how to add icon in button that's aligned to the left and make it either black or white?

Tags: html, css

[image]

```
 <style> 
span.icon {
 background: url(lock.png) no-repeat;
 float: left; 
width: 40px;
 height: 40px; 
} 
</style> 

<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log Me In"/><span class="icon">
```

So the icon won't show. I've got the icon but it's not working. I tried to add quotes to the file name but still no luck.

Comment: no this is a custom icon

Comment: @Satya how do I make it white or black?

Comment: if its jquery add the tag too

Comment: @ Wesley : If I do <img src="blah.ico class="blah">

.blah { background: white; }

Is that going to work?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/o0caKSB.png  made it black

Comment: Try something like this for starters: http://css3button.net/,  http://css3buttongenerator.com/, http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/, http://www.bestcssbuttongenerator.com/ The only part you'll need an image for is the "lock".

Comment: @ Wesley that's what I need I already have my own button I wana make the lock white or black.

Comment: Then you'll need photoshop/gimp or some image editing program. Did you have a programming or HTML/CSS question?

Comment: Okay why isn't this working:

<style>
span.icon {
    background: url(lock.png) no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
</style>


<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Log Me In"/><span class="icon"></span>

Comment: @ Wesley that's my html/css question

Comment: @user2309648 Firstly, no space if you want the ping to work; secondly, add your code to the question.

Comment: @Daedalus there i have changed the question with my code

Comment: I think I should make a new question

Comment: @user2309648 Don't; it will be closed as a duplicate.  What you need to concentrate on is making this one better.  Can you create a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) of the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

Since the icon is an image file and not a font, you can't change its color with CSS. You can, however, swap out the image for a properly colored version.

```
input{
    background:green url("http://placehold.it/50/ffffff") 10px center no-repeat;
}
input:hover{
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/50/000000");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/tvNCa/2/

You may also want to look into [CSS Sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/) for things like this.

Answer (score 0):

You would use an image editing program to make a button like that yourself or to decolor that image. To make it black you can desaturate it (or turn it into a black and white document) and change the levels to make it darker. It would probably still be best to make a new button on your own, though. There are many good looking button tutorials for gimp, photoshop, paint.net or other programs that you can find through google.

Answer (score -2):

I made it black using microsoft paint lol.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GRCZ.png
[image]