# Adding an icon to a button that's right beside the text

Tags: html, css

I want to make a button like this [ icon.png text-here ]

So that the button has an icon then text .

my code so far:

[css]

```
.icon {
    background: url('icon.png');
    float: right;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
}
```

[html]

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="icon" value="Log Me In"/><input type="button" id="cls" value="Clear All"/>
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: A button can only have text values.  To do what (I think) you're asking, you'd have to create an element that looked and acted like a button, but isn't actually <input type='button'>

Comment: You started a new account for this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/17508870/398242

Comment: So what should I do please guide me more

Comment: @Gary so i'm using this
.btn span.icon {
    background: url('lock.png') no-repeat;
    float: left;
    width: 10px;
    height: 40px;
}
<div class="btn btn_red"><span class="icon"></span><a href="#">Link</a><span></span></div>

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Just add positioning to the icon and some CSS to style the rest of the button.

HTML

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" class="icon" value="Log Me In"/>
```

CSS

```
input{
                 /* Change `http://placehold.it/50x50` to your icon */
    background:green url("http://placehold.it/50x50") 10px center no-repeat;
    height: 75px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 70px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/tvNCa/1/

Answer (score -1):

I think this is the easiest way

```
<button type="submit">some text <i class="icon"></i></button>


.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/16x16&text=icon");
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px; 
}
```

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/dXdF2/1/

Comment: The use of `<i>` for an icon is a very bad practice